# Android Studio - Scaffold - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit){
    MovieAppTheme {
        Scaffold(topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Movies", color = Color.White) },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.TopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    navigationIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    actionIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
                )
            )
        },) { content() }
    }
}
```

in above code i am unable to access TopAppBarColors properties also i am unable to find a way to show my content

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call wrong function. You have to call `topAppBarColors()`. See below.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyApp(content: @Composable (paddingValues: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    DONETheme {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = { Text(text = "Movies", color = Color.White) },
                    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    navigationIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    actionIconContentColor =  MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
                )
            )
        }) { paddingValues ->
            content(paddingValues)
        }
    }
}
```